# Ripple effect is not working in sliding tab layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to obtain ripple effect on clicking the tabs in the sliding tab layout, but it is not working.

custom_tab_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tabContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="15dp"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tabImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_bg"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tabText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom|center" />
```

Below is the drawable xml file to get the ripple effect

v22/tab_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
<item
    android:id="@+id/mask"
    android:drawable="@color/white"></item>
</ripple>
```

Below is the MainActivity where i have implemented the colors for background and indicator for the sliding tab.

MainActivty.java

```
  mTabs.setCustomTabView(R.layout.custom_tab_layout, R.id.tabText);
    mTabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);

    mTabs.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    mTabs.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.accentColor));
    mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);
```

Any Help is appreciated..!!

Comment: i guess you set wrong path `v22`  (v22/tab_bg.xml). set this `res/drawable` .https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect/

Comment: I updated my code. My mobile is lollipop version. Ripple effect is not supported in older version where i have to use selector. So i have given the code in v22 folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a library for getting ripple effect in sliding tab. Let me post both the files here.

1. In Android Studio, add dependency in build.gradle (compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11')

   Refer this https://github.com/neokree/MaterialTabs
2. activity_tab_library.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"

   tools:context="com.example.ramz.material_udemy_slidnerd.TabLibrary">

   <include
   android:id="@+id/app_bar"
   layout="@layout/app_bar" />

   <!-- for Text Tabs -->
   <it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost
   android:id="@+id/materialTabHost"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="48dp"

   app:accentColor="#FF9800"
   app:primaryColor="#673AB7"
   app:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
   android:id="@+id/viewPager"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"

   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:layout_weight="1"/>

   </LinearLayout>
   ```

   3.TabLibrary.java

   ```
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
   import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   import it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTab;
   import it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost;
   import it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabListener;


   public class TabLibrary extends AppCompatActivity implements MaterialTabListener {

   private MaterialTabHost tabHost;
   private ViewPager viewPager;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_library);
   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

   tabHost = (MaterialTabHost) findViewById(R.id.materialTabHost);
   viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

   ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
   viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
   //  viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
   viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onPageSelected(int posiiton) {
           tabHost.setSelectedNavigationItem(posiiton);
       }
   });
   for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
       tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTab().setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i)).setTabListener(this));
   }


   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_using_library, menu);
   return true;
   }
   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
   // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
   // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
   int id = item.getItemId();

   //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
   if (id == R.id.action_settings) {


       return true;
   }

   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }



   @Override
   public void onTabSelected(MaterialTab materialTab) {
   viewPager.setCurrentItem(materialTab.getPosition());

   }

   @Override
   public void onTabReselected(MaterialTab tab) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onTabUnselected(MaterialTab tab) {

   }

   public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

   public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
       super(fm);
   }

   @Override
   public Fragment getItem(int num) {
       return MainActivity.Myfragment.getInstance(num);
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       return 3;
   }

   @Override
   public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
       return getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs)[position];

   }

   }

   }
   ```

   That's all, we can add any number of tabs here.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In your SlidingTabLayout.java -> createDefaultTabView()
you will find

```
TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
```

just add background of this as **selectableItemBackground**

```
getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground, outValue, true);
```

for reference see this [SlidingTabLayout (Gist)](https://gist.github.com/SureshCS-50/345483b12a368f7bf433).

**Edit :**

Fine now i got your issue..
set your **custom_tab_layout.xml** background as **selectableItemBackground**

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use TabLayout from Android Design support

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

Layout:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
...
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:tabBackground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
```

See also tutorial for using custom layout
https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout